# How to access personal wiki (html files) securely over the internet

Tags: html

I have a load of html files that hyperlink between each other like a wiki. They contain personal info that I don't want to be public. But they are best viewed via a browser.

At the moment they are all in my Dropbox. So I can access the files via the mobile Dropbox app, but viewing the html files in this way doesn't allow use of the hyperlinks.

Any thoughts on how to:

a) enable true 'browser' access to the html files, with full hyperlink, CSS and image support

b) but keep the files private so that they could only be accessed with eg a password or login.

I'm using Mac OS X and iOS.

Comment: I think you need to explain your constraints a little more because the obvious solution would be to use SSL and a login page. This can be done with Wordpress, for instance, for free.

Comment: I think you just need an authentication. Enable basic auth for your website.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being thick, but why can't you use hyperlinks on the pages?

Comment: Hi, I can't use hyperlinks on the pages when viewing the html files using Dropbox for iOS app. On the Mac, the links work just fine, because I can view the files in a regular browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want any third-party to see the files (too late, of course; you put them on Dropbox) then you'd have to host them on your own computer, and set up a way to securely connect to that computer from the Internet. As it is, you can either host the files yourself, or have a trusted third party do so for you.

So, there's two basic ways to do this. For either one, you can use your own computer, or use some third-party provider like a website hosting company or a "cloud service" (i.e. somebody else's computer that you pay them to let you use).

1. Set up an HTTPS web server (on a publicly-reachable IP address that is either static, or uses dynamic DNS) that requires client authentication. This can be done using a login page with a username/password combo, or using HTTP authentication (basic or digest), or using a TLS client certificate. You then use your browser to connect to the web server (over HTTPS), authenticate either using username+password or client cert, and browse away. This approach is subject to web application security risks (like cross-site scripting or cross-site request forgery), but is the most seamless.
2. Set up a way to make a secure connection to the host computer over the Internet. This could be a VPN server, an SSH server, a Remote Desktop (Windows, mostly) server... etc. Anything that requires authentication and sets up a secure channel works. You would then be able to remotely log into your server from anywhere, and browse the files on it, including your HTML pages. This approach is more complicated to set up and use (you can't just point the browser at a URL, you have to first establish a tunnel to the server) but might be easier to keep secure.

Comment: Thanks @CBHacking. Option 1 sounds like the way to go. Do you know where I should look for enabling HTTP authentication? I do not currently have a web site or anything like that. Also, the very simplest way for me would be to enable HTTP authentication on my Dropbox 'Public' folder, and then put the files in there. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: HTTP Auth is a web server setting. To use it, you'll need to set up a web server (or get a hosting provider to do so for you), turn on the authentication feature, and specify a username and password that the server will accept. Some servers, such as Microsoft's IIS, will let you use system credentials (your Windows account) to log in, rather than requiring you set up a custom username/password combo. If you're setting up a server yourself, search a string like `httpd enable http authentication`.

Comment: I'm not actually familiar with Dropbox's public folders, but most likely that approach wouldn't work. First of all, Dropbox isn't a web host; you can grant access to Dropbox users (or to the world), but you can't control the auth scheme used. Second, Dropbox (Public or otherwise) would still have the problem with the hyperlinks between pages not working like you expect (for security purposes, Dropbox can't just directly serve HTML pages (or you could effectively add your own pages to Dropbox's website, which is a huge danger because it bypasses same-origin policy).